# MySQL does not reliably return Primary Key from mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql, insert, primary-key

In the over 10 years I have been developing PHP and mySQL solutions I have never seen this strange behavior, it almost seems like it must be a bug but I figured I would see if anyone has experienced this before.

We recently migrated to a brand new webserver running PHP 5.3.3 (mysql server runs on a different server, unchanged).

We have an order page using basically the same code we have been using with a few small edits, but nothing that should have anything to do with this error since the mysql queries have not been edited.

When trying to retrieve the primary key from the INSERT on the "customers" table it returns "0" about 60% of the time, and this is despite the record actually being inserted into the table.

The 60% of the time it does not return the primary key the record is being inserted and no errors are being returned.

```
IE:
//schema id (primary, auto inc), name (varchar 100)
mysql_query("insert into customers set name='john doe'");
echo mysql_error(); //never outputs an error, record above is inserted 100% of the time without problem and is properly assigned a auto incremented ID so it is not a parse error
$id = mysql_insert_id(); 
echo mysql_error(); //never outputs an error
echo $id; //60% of the time this is returned as "0" instead of the primary key that was just entered
```

PHP 5.3.3 Mysql 5.0.95

At first I thought it might be related to using SSL for the queries (turned on because we are two different servers in the same colo) so I turned that off to test and it seemed to resolve the problem at first, but then it started doing it again.

The only other thing I can think is perhaps it is losing connection with the mysql server, but I would think it would return "false" and output a mysql error if that were the case.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? The table is intact, and I've ran repair/optimize just to be sure. I'm at a loss for this random occurrence.

Since the code is virtually identical as it was running on the old server, I suspect it might be a bug and/or server setup issue. On the old server we were running Worker MPM with FCGID and php 5.1. On this server we are running Worker MPM with FastGCI PHP-FPM and PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Try a standard query of `SELECT last_insert_id() AS lid` instead of `mysql_insert_id()` and post, if this fixes the problem

Comment: Why is your "brand new" server running a version of PHP from 2010?

Comment: `I can think is perhaps it is losing connection with the mysql server, but I would think it would return "false"` .. NO, it will return 0 even if the connection to the DB is lost. moreover, `mysql_insert_id()` is a deprecated one.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` is designed to return 0 if you insert multiple rows in a single INSERT statement. Are you sure you're seeing 0 returned intermittently from the *same* single-row `INSERT`?

Comment: tadman - We have a bunch of older software that is not compatible 5.4+

Comment: bill - It is definitely not more than one insert. The code written above how I am testing it. Also mysql_query() does not support multiple queries in a single statement as far as I know.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same connection for both queries?

Answer (score 1):

Only two possible reasons i can find out here:

1. It is possible that your table does not have any AUTO_INCREMENT field! but you mentioned that you have this. and another is
2. It could also happen because you have two or more mysql connections at the same time. In this case you should use a link identifier. ex.

   $link = mysql_connect( ... );
   mysql_select_db('mydb', $link);
   mysql_query("insert into customers set name='john doe'", $link);
   $inserted_id = mysql_insert_id($link);